# Cannot get detail from emails forwarded to a Group (conversion thread)

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

When forwarding an email from Outlook to an Office365 group, the message shows in the group conversations and all details of the forwarded email.  This can be seen both in Outlook desktop and Outlook on the web.  But when using Microsoft.graph to read the same it does not display the forwarded message, only the body of the email used to forward the email.  How to get the forwarded message using the Microsoft graph?  Where is it stored?

The Graph Explorer does not show the details, nor does the SDK if the email is forwarded from Outlook.  But when forwarding from Gmail the details shows in the Graph Explorer and the SDK.

```
var Posts = await GraphClient
 .Groups[FromGroupID]
 .Threads[Thread.Id]
 .Posts
 .Request()
 .GetAsync();
```

If the forwarded message contains attachment it can be found using the SDK.

```
var attachments = await graphClient.Groups[FromGroupID]
 .Threads[Thread.Id]
 .Posts[post.Id]
 .Attachments
 .Request()
 .GetAsync();
```

But not the body, of the forwarded message and same works for Graph Explorer.  Outlook can still display both the attachment and the body.